# "Server" response header for Kestrel behind IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

If I host my Kestrel-based ASP.NET Core website with `UseIISIntegration` behind IIS, should the `Server` response header still say that I'm using Kestrel? Because it seems that it is:

[image]

Is it a correct behavior?

Comment: Well, technically its correct as Kestrel is hosting the application. IIS only serves as reverse proxy

Comment: @Tseng How can I check whether the website actually using IIS then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it should still report the application as hosted by Kestrel.

When you use IIS to host an ASP.NET Core application, you're really using IIS as a reverse proxy to Kestrel. This is the approach recommended by the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#choosing-a-server):

> If you intend to deploy your application on a Windows server, you should run IIS as a reverse proxy server that manages and proxies requests to Kestrel.

An incoming request will be handled first by IIS, and then passed on to Kestrel, like this:

**Web -> IIS -> ASP.NET Core module -> Kestrel**

So it's still accurate to say that Kestrel is the server handling the request. IIS is just sitting in front, helping Kestrel deal with the incoming traffic. You can check whether the site has been set up and assigned to an app pool in the IIS Manager if you want to determine whether it's using IIS (which should be the default).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer to the question, but since Google gave me this related answer to my question it might help some people:

**To remove this "server" header**, an option has been added to the Kestrel Startup Options, so in program.cs you can remove it by adding the following option:

```
.UseKestrel(o => { o.AddServerHeader = false; })
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserveroptions.addserverheader?view=aspnetcore-2.0) (quite poor)